# Connecting lines between points plotted in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 X and Y lists that I am plotting separately with matplotlib.pyplot, i.e. point1[x1,y1], point2[x2,y2], point3[x3,y3] and point4[x4,y4]. What I am trying to do in the plot is to connect point1 to point2, point2 to point3, etc. until all 4 points are connected which would represent a square in my case. The data is for dynamic x and y displacements for a rectangular pump I'm working on that shows if a displacement limitation is exceeded inside a vessel's moonpool.

Here is the code I have so far that gives me the following plot and the plot generated:

[image: Generated plot]

```
## SSLP displacement time histories to be plotted
point1 = (3.61, 4, -3)
point2 = (3.61, -4, -3)
point3 = (-3.61, -4, -3)
point4 = (-3.61, 4, -3)
SSLPXPoint1 = SSLP.TimeHistory('X', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point1))
SSLPYPoint1 = SSLP.TimeHistory('Y', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point1))
SSLPXPoint2 = SSLP.TimeHistory('X', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point2))
SSLPYPoint2 = SSLP.TimeHistory('Y', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point2))
SSLPXPoint3 = SSLP.TimeHistory('X', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point3))
SSLPYPoint3 = SSLP.TimeHistory('Y', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point3))
SSLPXPoint4 = SSLP.TimeHistory('X', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point4))
SSLPYPoint4 = SSLP.TimeHistory('Y', 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeBuoy(point4))

# setup plot
caseName = os.path.splitext(info.modelFileName)[0]
point1Plot = [3.61, 4]
point2Plot = [3.61, -4]
point3Plot = [-3.61, -4]
point4Plot = [-3.61, 4]
vesselPointsX = [90.89, 100.89, 100.89, 90.89, 90.89]
vesselPointsY = [5, 5, -5, -5, 5]
moonpoolCLX = [89, 103]
moonpoolCLY = [0, 0]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot(vesselPointsX, vesselPointsY, 'r', lw=2, label='OCV Moonpool Limits')
plt.plot(moonpoolCLX, moonpoolCLY, 'k--', label='Moonpool CL')
plt.plot(SSLPXPoint1, SSLPYPoint1, 'k')
plt.plot(SSLPXPoint2, SSLPYPoint2, 'k')
plt.plot(SSLPXPoint3, SSLPYPoint3, 'k')
plt.plot(SSLPXPoint4, SSLPYPoint4, 'k')
ax.set_title("SSLP Maximum Offsets Inside Moonpool for {}".format(caseName), fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance Along OCV from Stern [m]', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Distance from Moonpool Centerline, (+) Towards Portside [m]', fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlim(89, 103)
ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.draw()
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Create a list of X of points and second list of Y of points and `plt.plot(list_x, list_y)` this should work.

Comment: Thank you! That worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you. Make your changes.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
plot([SSLPXPoint1, SSLPXPoint2], [SSLPYPoint1, SSLPYPoint2])
plot([SSLPXPoint3, SSLPXPoint2], [SSLPYPoint3, SSLPYPoint2])
plot([SSLPXPoint3, SSLPXPoint4], [SSLPYPoint3, SSLPYPoint4])
show()
```

Edited, because previous one was connecting all dots.

Comment: Welcome, I've edited, but then realized that both works. :)

Comment: I tested both and you're right. The results are identical. It's great to know more than one way to do it though!